# Angular2 - ngfactory files are not generated for ahead of time compilation

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am trying to make `Angular2` `AoT` working. Unfortunatelly .ngfactory files are not generated when I execute `ngc` command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p "./tsconfig-aot.json" --i18nFile="./app/compiled/localise.xlf" --locale=zh --i18nFormat=xlf
```

With that configuration my 'JIT' compilation works fine, until `ngc` command is run, then it breaks `JIT` as well until rebuild of solution.

Error it gives:

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https:// <domain>/<urlPath>/traceur
       Error: XHR error (404) loading https:// <domain>/<urlPath>/traceur
           at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (https://<domain>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [<root>]
           at Zone.runTask (https:// <domain>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (https:// <domain>/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) [<root>]
       Error loading https:// <domain>/<urlPath>/traceur
       Unable to load transpiler to transpile https:// <domain>/<pathToMain>/main.js
       Error loading https://<domain>/<pathToMain>/main.js
```

My configuration:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "aspnet",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "@types/node": "6.0.57",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rollup": "0.40.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-multi-entry": "^2.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig-aot.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "app/compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/app.module.ts",
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "app/compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

And the `TypeScript` in version `2.0.2`.

`Angular` and all the packages has been updated to latest versions, but didn't help.

`npm install` been called, and generated `node_modules`.

`gulp` has been called and `libs` directory has been created as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is 2.0.2? Can you remove the caret(^), remove the lib, install the dependency and try again? Like this:  `"typescript": "2.0.2"`

Comment: you made my day. Could you please add it as answer so I can accept that? Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be 2.0.2 since you have a caret(`^`) in your package json.

Remove the caret(`^`), remove the lib, install the dependency and try again.

Like this: `"typescript": "2.0.2"`

Comment: do you know why `AoT` is breaking `JIT`? It's working well now, but still affecting `JIT` compilation. I am just trying to understand this a little bit better.

Comment: @MadOX Unfortunately I haven't tried `AoT` to its fullest yet in my build :( so I don't want to say anything wrong.

Comment: @MadOX AoT 'breaks' JIT because `tsconfig-aot.json` has `"module": "es2015"`. Which means your code gets compiled to something that has to be transpiled inside the browser. That's why SystemJS is trying to load `traceur` (the transpiler :)). AoT needs the code to be like this, because it can use tree-shaking after that

Comment: @PierreDuc other words - not a chance to have a separation on that, other than just not call AoT commands if you want go for JIT. I wanted to have AoT as a build step.

Comment: @MadOX not really, only use AoT if you want to go to production.. But, another option could be to use [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/). It's very easy to let your project use the cli, and that way all the JIT/AoT/prod/build is taken care of as it should be